# Show an image in a blade file after using Intervention Image (Laravel)

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-blade, intervention

I want to show an image in a blade template that contains already some HTML code after doing some modifications (resize, insert...) to this image using the Intervention Image library.

Example :

```
public function image(){
    return $img = Image::make('images/test.jpg')
        ->resize(800, 500)
        ->insert('some_url', 'bottom-right', 10, 10)
        ->text('foo', 100, 100, function($font) {
            $font->file('fonts/font.ttf');
            $font->size(100);
            $font->color('#fdf6e3');})
        ->response();
}
```

This method is called using this route :

```
Route::get('/image', 'MyController@image');
```

The result is perfect :)
but I want to show this image in a blade template that contains already HTML code, and not just return the image using the route.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want to store this image and access it again in a blade view? I assume there will only be one of these images right?

Comment: No, without storing the image, I want to show the result after modifications in blade view.

Comment: No there is an undefined number of images.

Answer (score 0):

Try just setting returned like this `<img src="$img">` in your blade.